# Find the most frequent element in flann matrix type

Tags: c++, flann

What is the best way to find the most frequent element of flann matrix such as `flann::Matrix<int> k_indices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose that you to declare a `map<int,int> counters`, then insert each element of your Matrix into the map and if the element already exist just increment the relative counter:

```
map<int,int> counters;
...
if(counters.count(yourNumber)==0)
   counters[yourNumber] = 1
else
   counters[yourNumber]++
```

and after get the counter of last element:

```
return counters.rbegin()->second;
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: This method takes extra memory, still I accept it. Thanks.

Comment: yes you're right! Here memory complexity is O(N) where N is the number of different elements in the Matrix. So it really depends on the range of elements (small, large...). A less memory consumption solution should exist but maybe less efficient considering run time. It's always a tradeoff between memory vs run time.